# iOS 13 getVoiceShortcut Not Returning INVoiceShortcut, Just nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri, sirishortcuts

Following worked fine till iOS 13:

```
INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getVoiceShortcut(with: uuid) { (invoiceShortcut, error) in

  //invoiceShortcut returned is always nil

}
```

uuid I am feeding in is double checked to be right.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is `error` nil?

Comment: Error is also nil.

Comment: Having the same issue @Gizmodo!!